# Cannot access "multiverse" in the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 11.10, software-center, multiverse

I can't seem to access "muiltiverse" in the software center.  I have it checked in the settings, but when I search for libhighgui, which is in multiverse, it doesn't show up.  Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Seems to show up for me in USC, can you add the contents of your /etc/apt/sources.list to your question or a screenshot of your software settings?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11410095&postcount=2021

After that, run in a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libhighgui
```

Then it should install it.

Comment: Still doesn't work I'm afraid.

I'm not new to ubuntu, so I've used different repositories in the past, it's just not working lately.  I tried it on my laptop and my desktop (both 64bit).

Comment: OK, I edited my answer.